# Multiline search/replace in Vim without escaping

Tags: vim, replace

It's a very typical for me to copy a text to clipboard, and replace all occurrences of that text with something else. I have no clue how to use Vim's `:substitute` to do so. You can insert the content of a register with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>`register`, but you would still have to escape the text, and I couldn't find any reasonable way to do it with a multiline text.

Say you want to replace `FROM @SERVER: PING :/\SERVER<CR>command: ping, source: None, target: @SERVER, arguments: ['@SERVER']` which you already have in register `q` with `ACK @SERVER1` in the text below:

Sample text:

```
FROM @SERVER: PING :/\SERVER
command: ping, source: None, target: @SERVER, arguments: ['@SERVER']
TO @SERVER: PONG SERVER
FROM @SERVER: PING :/\SERVER
command: ping, source: None, target: @SERVER, arguments: ['@SERVER']
TO @SERVER: PONG /\SERVER
FROM SERVER: user2 PRIVMSG !CNL :#user1: what's up?
command: pubmsg, source: #user2, target: !CNL, arguments: ["#user1: what's up?"]
FROM @SERVER: PING :/\SERVER
command: ping, source: None, target: @SERVER, arguments: ['@SERVER']
TO @SERVER: PONG /\SERVER
FROM @SERVER: PING :/\SERVER
command: ping, source: None, target: @SERVER, arguments: ['@SERVER']
TO @SERVER: PONG /\SERVER
```

Comment: make a concrete example pls. were you trying to do a literal replacement? then `\V` may help you.

Comment: @Kent doint a `/\Vexpr` is good for searching for a single-line text, I need to do that for search/replace.

Comment: again, make a concrete example pls!

Comment: @Kent I just found out it's possible to use \V in a replace (`:%s/\V<C-r><C-r>"/TEXT/g`) and that solves half the problem, thanks. Is there anything I can use for a multiline text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first two lines of your example in the default register (e.g. via `y2$`), you can build a replacement command like this:

```
:%s/\V<C-r>=substitute(escape(@@, '/\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')<CR>/REPLACEMENT/g
```

What it does:

- literal matching via `\V`
- backslashes still need to be escaped, and the `/` separator of `:substitute`, too
- a newline needs to be translated to the `\n` regular expression atom
- all of that is inserted into the command-line via `<C-r>` and the *expression register*